# longer (noun; 'one who longs') vs. longer (adj; 'more long') — pronounced differently?

Tags: pronunciation

Am I construing [John Lawler](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/15299/john-lawler)'s comment [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13860/origin-of-ing#comment230030_13862) correctly? Lawler was pairing words as Minimal Pairs. You can use IPA in your answer. Even better, if you can record and embed audio for this Minimal Pair!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they would be pronounced differently. The one related to length would have a /g/.

"Longer" meaning "one who longs" seems pretty unlikely to me. Hence, in the attached recording, I've added "not attested"... :)

[Click here for audio demonstration](https://unfamiliarplace.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/longer.wav)

Comment: Of course, if you come from Lancashire, finger/singer/ringer are all full rhymes, all with the harder G. I've never heard them tackle 'one who longs' but i could imagine it would be similar.

Comment: @gonefishin'again. That's true. You can often hear it in Beatles songs.